# Service Worker not receiving message

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

NOTE: Using Create-React-App Template... (Modifying the Service Worker in it)

I am using the communication channel api to send a message to a service worker for caching. I use an xmlhttp request because of its progress api since fetch needs an indefinite loader afaik.

So after receiving the data on readystate 4 and status code 200 I go to postMessage to SW. I get logging on client side but don't receive the message in the service worker.

I am developing locally and using a Chrome Extension to allow local testing of SW and Build:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

CLIENT SNIPPET

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        const res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        function sendMessage(msg){
            console.log("SEND SW MESSAGE");
            const msgChan = new MessageChannel();
            // This wraps the message posting/response in a promise, which will resolve if the response doesn't
            // contain an error, and reject with the error if it does. If you'd prefer, it's possible to call
            // controller.postMessage() and set up the onmessage handler independently of a promise, but this is
            // a convenient wrapper.
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                console.log("Promise Scope");

                msgChan.port1.onmessage = function(event){
                    event.data.error ? reject(event.data.error) : resolve(event.data);
                }
                // This sends the message data as well as transferring messageChannel.port2 to the service worker.
                // The service worker can then use the transferred port to reply via postMessage(), which
                // will in turn trigger the onmessage handler on messageChannel.port1.
                // See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#dom-worker-postmessage
                navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(msg, [msgChan.port2]);
            });
        }

        sendMessage(res).then(function(){
            console.log("SW MESSAGE SENT");
            // Storing Quake Data
            that.props.setQuakes(res[0]);
            // Storing Three Data Obj - SSR Parsing and Creation
            that.props.setThreeData(res[1]);   
            // Greenlight 
            that.props.setVizInitSuccess(true);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Error Caching Data: "+err);
        });
    } };
```

SERVICE WORKER SNIPPET

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      // Set up a listener for messages posted from the service worker.
      // The service worker is set to post a message to all its clients once it's run its activation
      // handler and taken control of the page, so you should see this message event fire once.
      // You can force it to fire again by visiting this page in an Incognito window.
      navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log("SERVICE WORKER RECIEVED MESSAGE");
        console.log(event);

        event.ports[0].postMessage("SW Says Hello Back!");
        if (event.data.requireData == true && 'caches' in window) {
          // Check for cache'd data and load
          // clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
          //     clients.forEach(client => {
          //         console.log(client);
          //         //send_message_to_client(client, msg).then(m => console.log("SW Received Message: "+m));
          //     })
          // })

          // caches.open('threeData').then(function(cache){
          //   console.log("SW Cache");
          //   console.log(cache)
          //   event.ports[0].postMessage(cache);  
          // });

        } else {
          // Cache Data
          caches.open('threeData').then(function(cache){
            cache.put('/data.json', new Response(event.data.json))
          });
        }
      };
...
```

Comment: Try the `self.addEventListener` approach mentioned in http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html

Answer (score 4):

`navigator` used in Service Worker file is **WorkerNavigator** Interface and not **Navigator** Interface.

**WorkerNavigator** is a  subset of the **Navigator** interface allowed to be accessed from a Worker *(In this case its Service worker)*.
[WorkerNavigator Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator).

So `navigator` inside Service worker file doesn't contains `serviceWorker` object. So it throws error when you call `navigator.serviceWorker.onMessage`.

To receive the messages from client use `self.addEventListener` in **Service Worker file**.

```
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log(`[Message] event: `, event.data);
});
```

Comment: So it's rather interesting in the Create React App template I used. If I edit that service worker file and use self it errors out saying cannot use that variable name like its a protected global or something. However, if I create a new file and a worker from scratch then I am able to use it.

Comment: Actually the `serviceWorker.js` in create-react-app is not actually the registered service worker. This file registers a service worker in `registerValidSW` function providing a `swUrl`. That `service-worker.js` file is generated by using workbox. If you inspect them in Applications tab of chrome dev tools. `service-worker.js` is present which uses **Workbox**.

Comment: Yeah I had to create a different service worker to make use of any self scope. Replace the workbox service worker in registerValidSW with a custom worker. Seems like the workbox worker is only good for your basic caching since it's harder to customize heavily.